# gluLookAt Issues

Tags: opengl, camera, rendering, curves, bspline

I've been trying to create a roller coaster simulator in OpenGL which uses a series of gluLookAt calls to make the camera 'ride' the roller coaster. The coaster itself is based on a b-spline curve with control points in the coords array. b0(u), b1(u) etc are the blending functions for b-spline curves, with bprime0(u) etc being their derivatives. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        for (float u = 0; u <= 1.1; u+=0.1){

            x = (b0(u)*coords[(i)%10].x + b1(u)*coords[(i+1)%10].x
                + b2(u)*coords[(i+2)%10].x + b3(u)*coords[(i+3)%10].x)*2.0f;
            y = (b0(u)*coords[(i)%10].y + b1(u)*coords[(i+1)%10].y
                + b2(u)*coords[(i+2)%10].y + b3(u)*coords[(i+3)%10].y)*2.0f;
            z = (b0(u)*coords[(i)%10].z + b1(u)*coords[(i+1)%10].z
                + b2(u)*coords[(i+2)%10].z + b3(u)*coords[(i+3)%10].z)*2.0f;

            xprime = (bprime0(u)*coords[(i)%10].x + bprime1(u)*coords[(i+1)%10].x
                    + bprime2(u)*coords[(i+2)%10].x + bprime3(u)*coords[(i+3)%10].x)*-2.0f;
            yprime = (b0(u)*coords[(i)%10].y + bprime1(u)*coords[(i+1)%10].y
                    + bprime2(u)*coords[(i+2)%10].y + bprime3(u)*coords[(i+3)%10].y)*-2.0f;
            zprime = (b0(u)*coords[(i)%10].z + bprime1(u)*coords[(i+1)%10].z
                    + bprime2(u)*coords[(i+2)%10].z + bprime3(u)*coords[(i+3)%10].z)*-2.0f;

            Coords nvector = {xprime,yprime,zprime};
            float magn = sqrt(nvector.x*nvector.x+nvector.y*nvector.y+nvector.z*nvector.z);
            nvector.x= nvector.x/magn;
            nvector.y= nvector.y/magn;
            nvector.z= nvector.z/magn;

            glLoadIdentity();
            if (rotateCam == 1){
                theta+=0.0001;
                if (theta > 360) {
                    theta = 0;
                }
                gluLookAt(20*cos(theta),15,20*sin(theta),0,0,0,0,1,0);
                }//if
            else{
                printf("%f\t%f\t%f\n", x+xprime,y+yprime,z+zprime);
                gluLookAt(x,y+1,z,x+xprime,y+yprime,z+zprime,0,1,0);
            }//else

        }//for
}//for
```

The spacebar switches the 'rotateCam' variable, which is supposed to switch between two viewing modes; one which circles the camera around the coaster (the 'if' statement) and one which rides the coaster (the 'else' statement).

Here's the thing: the circling mode works fine, and switching between modes works fine, but the camera is always stationary in the 'ride' mode. The printf statement shows that x, xprime, y, yprime etc are all changing with each timer tick, but the camera never moves.

If more code is needed let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by the camera is always stationary in the ride mode?

Answer (score 0):

`gluLookAt` doesn't position the cemera, it only rotates it to the correct angle.  After this it is up to you to also translate it.  So this should do the trick:

```
gluLookAt(x,y+1,z,x+xprime,y+yprime,z+zprime,0,1,0);
gluTranslated(x,y+1,z);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not doing anything for me. Shouldn't gluLookAt handle the movement, though, because you specify the 'eye' value? What confuses me most is that the other call, gluLookAt(20*cos(theta),15,20*sin(theta),0,0,0,0,1,0);, works perfectly.